# Change Emacs' background color

Tags: emacs, customization, emacs-faces

I have a function that sets Emacs' color theme to a theme defined by myself. In this function I do:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default cur-frame :foreground fg-color :background bg-color)
```

I then set the background color, foreground color, and cursor color for `default-frame-alist`, `initial-frame-alist` and `special-display-frame-alist`.

All of this works fine on my Mac. But when I use this on Linux, it looks fine for all frames that have already been opened, but on newly created frames it looks like this:

[image: background color issue]

I do not have this problem with new frames if use the `set-background-color` / `set-foreground-color` functions instead of (`set-face-attribute 'default ...`). But if I do that I have to manually reset the colors for every frame that's already open.

I am using Emacs version 23.3 on both Mac and Ubuntu.

For clarification, this is the theme file I use:

[my-color.el](https://bitbucket.org/brownstone/emacs_configuration/src/83edfb4bc0fb/my-color.el)

Comment: Does a `C-l` paint the colors properly?

Comment: @vpit3833 Nope. It scrolls the window down, but nothing changes.

Comment: Why don't you just use the color-theme mode?

Comment: @BozhidarBatsov I've tried all the themes, I hated them all. All I need is a couple of simple and clear themes, that I can switch back and forth on different occasions. So I decided make up my own. Everything works out fine until recently I realize this issue on Linux platform, since I've work on my Mac most of the time.

Comment: There are external themes compatible with color-theme as well, like - https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs (amongs many others). emacs 24 will have a built in theming capability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's better to use

```
(custom-set-faces
  '(default ... )
  '(region ... )
  ....
)
```

style to set faces, this way it will not have that problem.

Answer (score 6):

`set-face-attribute` sets, as the name suggest, the attributes of a face (i.e., font-related properties), not the attributes of the frame. Use

`(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "lightgray"))`

and similar to change frame-related properties.

Comment: This seems to work fine until I resize the window, after which the colors are broken again (emacs 24.4.1).

Answer (score 3):

```
(if (eq system-type 'darwin)
    ;; mac os x settings
  (if (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
    (setq default-frame-alist '((background-color . "black")
                                (foreground-color . "gray")))))
```

something like this should help you maintain settings per OS.

Comment: Actually, I have that already, if you are interested try it out, this is my emacs configuration repos on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/brownstone/emacs_configuration), it's in the file called my-color.el. The issue is that if I use set-face-attributes for 'default, new frames will be messed up, even if I set default-frame-alist. Without it, they would be fine, but I'll have to manually set every other opened frames one by one. Though generally there won't be that many frames, I still would like to make the change with one command.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs uses<sup>1)</sup> (or does not paint over) the Gtk3.0 theme background in more recent Emacs versions. Changing background using e.g. `set-background-color` or `default-frame-alist` only works until I resize the window, after which the Gtk theme background "shines through" again.

I have not yet been able to figure out how to get emacs to always paint over the Gtk theme background, but at least I have found a way how to change the Gtk theme background color, for Emacs only: https://superuser.com/questions/699501/emacs-showing-grey-background-where-there-are-no-characters/937749#937749

So this does not fully solve changing the background color when you switch themes, but at least you can get rid of the black-white contrast you experience when opening new frames.

*1) on my machine at least :)*